# MOCK_METHOD name must be followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest, googlemock

Given an interface class Foo:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
#include <string>
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo() = default;
        virtual ~Foo() = default;
        virtual void bar(std::string msg) = 0;
};
#endif
```

Its mock:

```
#ifndef FOO_MOCK_H
#define FOO_MOCK_H
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
class MockFoo: public Foo
{
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD(void, bar, (std::string), (override));
};
#endif
```

And a silly test:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "MockFoo.h"

using ::testing::NiceMock;

TEST(SillyTests, Silly)
{
    std::string msg = "Hello, world!";
    NiceMock<MockFoo> mock_foo;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock_foo, bar)
        .Times(1);
    mock_foo.bar(msg);
}
```

Among a bevy of errors internal to gtest and gmock, Visual Studio is complaining about `MOCK_METHOD()` that "name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name", and that no function definition for `MOCK_METHOD` is found.

Interestingly, adding the old function call `MOCK_METHODn` produces the same error.

```
MOCK_METHOD1(debug, void(std::string msg));
```

Hovering over the `MOCK_METHOD` shows several static asserts, but they don't seem to be correct. They include:

- `"(std::string)"` should be enclosed in parentheses (it is)
- `"(override)"` should be enclosed in parentheses (again, it is)
- Signature must be a function type, maybe return type contains unprotected comma (it is type `void`, adding parentheses doesn't correct this)
- This method does not take "1" arguments. Parenthesize all types with unprotected commas

gmock version is 1.10.0, Google Test adapter version is 1.8.1.3.

Comment: Is `<string>` included somewhere? And do you have include guards for your GenericLogger header?

Comment: `<string>` is included in GenericLogger.hpp, and I have include guards in GenericLogger, FooLogger, and MockLogger (`#ifndef`, not `#pragma once`).

Comment: Okay I had to ask because this isn't exactly a [mcve]. If you could give us one of those, that'd help :-)

Comment: Ah, give me a few and I'll do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. googlemock and googletest not sharing the same version was the cause. Downgrading googlemock to v1.8.1 corrected the issue.

Comment: Which versions of google test and google mock are you using?

Answer (score 4):

> This method does not take "1" arguments. Parenthesize all types with unprotected commas

Although what you're seeing could be different but I faced this and brought me here so adding my answer for related issue. Above quoted error could be because how macros are processed & here is what it's asking for:

```
// To mock following
virtual void func(int a, std::map<int, int> m) = 0

// This won't work since argument list enclosed parses by splitting
// using ',' and sees 3 arguments, int a, std::map<int and int> m.
MOCK_METHOD(void, func, (int a, std::map<int, int> m), (override));

// However properly paranthesizing it make it see just 2 arguments as expected and works:
MOCK_METHOD(void, func, (int a, (std::map<int, int> m)), (override));
```